# Calling ShiVa code from within iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, shiva3d

I'm still very new to ShiVa3d and fairly new to iOS.

I'd like to develop an app that runs on an iPad. I will write quite a lot of logic in objective-c that will run on the iOS and some simple lua code in ShiVa.

Here is a very simple example of what I'd like to do:

1) My app will have a single model, which will load and be viewed.

2) Inside my lua ShiVa code, as part of the MainAI, I will create a method that accepts parameters such as x,y,z let's call this method "ShiVaCameraToPostition(objX,objY,objZ)"

3) Inside my iOS objective-c code I want to call this "ShiVaCameraToPostition" method, with parameters

Is this possible?

How would I go about doing this? What should I look for in the documentation? Are there any examples people can point to?

Many thanks in advance. Please let me know if the above is ambiguous.

Comment: Shiva is dead. They make bogus v2.0 sale (at discounted price) but until 2 years later they still not release v2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, success of sorts. Please don't beat me over the head over best practice, I just wanted to get this going.

So, I created a class to do my dirty work in, let's call it ShivaInterface.

```
ShivaInterface.h
ShivaInterface.mm /*** note the .mm ***/
```

The header was as follows:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ShivaInterface : NSObject{

}

+(const void*)getMyParams:(NSNumber*)x andY:(NSNumber*)y;

@end
```

And implemented as:

```
#import "ShivaInterface.h"
#import "S3DXPlugin.h" //is this the correct thing to include? it worked for me

@implementation ShivaInterface

+(const void*)getMyParams:(NSNumber*)x andY:(NSNumber*)y{
    static S3DX::AIVariable args[2];
    args[0].SetNumberValue([x floatValue]);
    args[1].SetNumberValue([y floatValue]);
    return args;
}
@end
```

Then in my pure Obj-c method:

```
const void *params = [ShivaInterface getMyParams:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:100.0f] andY:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:100.0f]];
S3DClient_SendEventToCurrentUser("MainAi","onDoRotate",2,params);
```

That works, I realise it's not beautiful, and my lack of a deeper understanding of C/C++ probably doesn't help.

(Full thread here: http://www.stonetrip.com/developer/forum/viewtopic.php?p=29073#p29073)

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a ShiVa method it would seem, you must call a handler using:

`S3DClient_SendEventToCurrentUser("MainAI","onMyHandler",0);`

The 3rd and 4th parameters are number of arguments and the arguments in an array (need to look into that separately).